# Checking the number of param in bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, arguments

I use for checking the number of params in bash shell as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash
usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 <you need to specify at least 1 param>"
    exit -1
}
[ x = x$1 ] && usage
```

where, if [ x = x$1 ] condition is not satisfied, execute usage.
Here, my question is, I never really think about the expression [ x = x$1 ] which looks a lot like a condition expression. Is x counted as a literal? and how come can we use = for comparison. Typically should it be something like ==?

Could anybody please fill the void here?

Comment: `[ x = x$1 is ]` is an archaic trick from a time when one particular shell couldn't handle `[ "$1" = "" ]` correctly. It is no longer needed; testing against an empty string is safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[ x = x$1 ]` is error prone, don't use it. Do this instead `[ "$1" ]`

The difference is that if `$1` contains a space or other special characters, your script will crash, for example:

```
$ a='hello world'
$ [ x = x$a ] && echo works
-bash: [: too many arguments
```

To fix this you *could* do `[ x = x"$1" ]`, but `[ "$1" ]` is shorter, so what's the point.

`[]` expressions are used extensively in shell scripts, I recommend to read `help test`. The `[` is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must be a literal `]`, to match the opening `[`. In there you will find the explanation of the differences between `=` and `==` operators.

Finally, literal text in conditions is evaluated to true if not empty. Some more examples:

```
[ x ]       # true
[ abc ]     # true
[ a = a ]   # true
[ a = x ]   # false
[ '' ]      # false
[ b = '' ]  # false
```

Also common gotchas are these:

```
[ 0 ]       # true
[ -n ]      # true
[ -blah ]   # true
[ false ]   # true
```

These are true, because `0`, `-n`, `false` or anything being the only argument, they are treated as literal strings, and so the condition evaluates to true.

Comment: It certainly is easier to remember and use

Answer (score 1):

`[ x = y ]` condition is for comparing strings. (just once `=`)

`x$1` means concatenating two string `x` and `$1`.

So, if `$1` is empty, `x$1` equals `x`, and `[ x = x ]` will be true as a result.

Comment: I just found out that [ x == y ] and [x = y] are symantically the same.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-basic-operators.htm
I found many examples of '=', but a little one of '==' in string comparison. So, I searched for that when '==' is used, above page says it is used by arithmetic comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$#` to count the number of parameters and use the OR operator instead of the AND  so that `usage()` only gets executed if the first condition fails.

```
#! /bin/bash
usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 <you need to specify at least 1 param>"
    exit -1
}
[ x = $# ] || usage
```

Comment: Oh, maybe I was not clear about my question. My question is more likely, what does [x = x$1 ] mean? and shouldn't it be something like [ x == x$1 ]?